# Render array of hashes using rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rabl

I have the following hash in my controller.

```
@order = {
  :id => "somestringid",
  :user_id => "someotherstringid",
  :amount => 19.99,
  :metadata => [
    {
      :type => :shipping_data,
      :address => "line 1 of address, line 2 of address, city, state, pincode"
    },
    {
      :type => :payment,
      :stripe_customer_id => "somestringid",
      :stripe_card_id => "someotherstringid"
    },
    {
      :type => :contact,
      :email => "someone@example.com",
      :phone => "1231231231"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notes:

1. The "metadata" is a list of objects.
2. There can be 0, 1 or more metadata objects.
3. Each metadata object has a different structure.
4. The only common key for all metadata objects is the "type" key.

I want to use rabl to generate the following json, but cannot figure out what I should put into my template.

The JSON output that I want should look like the following.

```
{
  "id": "somestringid",
  "user_id": "someotherstringid",
  "amount": 19.99,
  "metadata": [
    {
      "type": "shipping_data",
      "address": "line 1 of address, line 2 of address, city, state, pincode"
    },
    {
      "type": "payment",
      "stripe_customer_id": "somestringid",
      "stripe_card_id": "someotherstringid"
    },
    {
      "type": "contact",
      "email": "someone@example.com",
      "phone": "1231231231"
    }
  ]
}
```

What should I put into my template, so that I get the desired output?

Comment: **Note** I am using `OpenStruct.new` to convert my hash to an object, as Rabl doesn't work with hashes.

Comment: I do not get the question. Your output is the exact JSON representation of your object.

Comment: @mudasobwa That's the desired output. That I am not able to generate.

Comment: `@order.to_json`?

Comment: @order isn't a rails model..

Comment: It doesn't have the json method. 
I could use `render :json @order` and that works fine, but the rest of my app is using rabl, and I wanted to find a way to do this using Rabl.

Comment: `#to_json` has nothing to do with Rails at all, it is defined on almost everything by `json.rb` from the standard ruby library. Producing json out of hashes is an internal ruby functionality, so I still do not understand what are you trying to achieve and I doubt I can be of any help here.

Comment: didn't know that about e`#to_json`. Thanks.. will try it out again.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

I am not sure whether by rabl you mean you are using standard [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) gem OR [rabl-rails](https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails) because you haven't provided any details about the nature of your application and it is built using what all libraries.

But my solution below is in context of a Rails application using **rabl-rails** gem. And the **rabl-rails** gem's README says following:

> rabl-rails is faster and uses less memory than the standard rabl gem while letting you access the same features. There are some slight changes to do on your templates to get this gem to work but it should't take you more than 5 minutes.

So I guess it should not be a problem to adapt this solution in context of standard **rabl** gem whether the application is built Rails or Non-Rails based. My aim is to provide a guidance on the approach which can be used to achieve your desired output.

**Now coming to the solution approach:**

Using some abstractions you can design a flexible and maintainable solution. Let me elaborate:

Assuming you have a plain ruby-class `Order` like following or if you don't have any such class you can define it easily using [virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) gem which provides some handy out-of-the-box features for a class:

**app/models/order.rb**

```
  class Order
    attr_accessor :id, :user_id, :amount, :order_metadata_obj_arr

    ....
    ..
  end
```

**app/models/order_metadata.rb**

```
  class OrderMetadata
    attr_accessor :metadata_type, :metadata_data_obj

    ...
    ...
  end
```

**app/models/shipping_data.rb**

```
  class ShippingData
    attr_accessor :address
  end
```

**app/models/payment_data.rb**

```
  class PaymentData
    attr_accessor :stripe_customer_id, :stripe_card_id
  end
```

**app/models/contact_data.rb**

```
  class ContactData
    attr_accessor :email, :phone
  end
```

**/app/json_views/orders/metadata/shipping.rabl**

```
attribute :address
```

**/app/json_views/orders/metadata/payment.rabl**

```
attribute :stripe_customer_id, :stripe_card_id
```

**/app/json_views/orders/metadata/contact.rabl**

```
attribute :email, :phone
```

**/app/json_views/orders/order_metadata.rabl**

```
attribute :type

# Anonymous node.
node do |order_metadata_obj|
  template_path = "./orders/metadata/#{order_metadata_obj.type}"
  metadata_data_obj = order_metadata_obj.metadata_data_obj
  partial(template_path, object: metadata_data_obj)
end
```

**/app/json_views/order.rabl**

```
  attributes :id, :user_id, :amount

  node(:metadata) do |order_obj|
    partial('./orders/order_metadata', object: order_obj.order_metadata_obj_arr)
  end
```

Then in your controller do this

**/app/controllers/my_controller.rb**

```
 class MyController < MyBaseController

    def my_action
      order_obj = create_order_obj_from_hash(order_hash)

      order_json = order_json_representation(order_obj)
      status = 200

      render json: order_json, status: status
    end

    private

    def create_order_obj_from_hash(order_hash)
      order_metadata_arr = order_hash[:metadata]

      order_metadata_obj_arr = []

      order_metadata_arr.each do |item_hash|
        md_type = item_hash[:type]

        md_obj = case md_type
                        when :shipping_data
                          ShippingData.new(address: item_hash[:address])
                        when :payment
                          PaymentData.new(stripe_customer_id: item_hash[:stripe_customer_id], stripe_card_id: item_hash[:stripe_card_id])
                        when :contact
                          ContactData.new(email: item_hash[:email], phone: item_hash[:phone])
                        else
                          // unsupported md_type
                      end

        unless md_obj.nil?
          omd_obj = OrderMetadata.new(metadata_type: md_type, metadata_data_obj: md_obj)
          order_metadata_obj_arr << omd_obj
        end
      end

      order_attrs = order_hash.slice(:id, :user_id, :amount)

      order = Order.new(order_attrs)
      order.order_metadata_obj_arr = order_metadata_obj_arr
      order
    end

    def order_json_representation(order_obj)
      template_name = "order.rabl"
      template_path = Rails.root.join("app", "json_views")
      RablRails.render(order_obj, template_name, view_path: template_path, format: :json)
    end
  end
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I am specifically looking for a solution where I can directly convert the hash to the json in my template. I cannot create all the boiler plate classes before hand. Thanks.

Comment: Then why don't you try the [Custom Nodes](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#custom-nodes) approach? You just need to make sure that in the `node` block the object passed is your Hash. You can use the templates I have given with the only difference that in your case the object passed to node's block will be your Hash instead of the objects of classes I have suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Found a solution using Custom nodes.